# Cloning issue for local HTTPS GitLab server with self-signed certificate

Tags: git, ssl, gitlab

I'm having problems cloning a local GitLab repository that is configured with HTTPS and uses a self-signed certificate.

I can access the GitLab HMI with Firefox and so on, but have problems performing git commands between a local repo to the servo repo (pull, push, clone, etc).

For example (IP changed to `123.123.123.123` and other paths changed):

`$ git clone https://123.123.123.123/MyName/MyProject.git`
`fatal: unable to access 'https://123.123.123.123/MyName/MyProject.git/': SSL: certificate subject name (123.123.123.123) does not match target host name '123.123.123.123'`

And just in case:

`$ git clone http://123.123.123.123/MyName/MyProject.git`
`fatal: unable to access 'http://123.123.123.123/MyName/MyProject.git/': Failed to connect to 123.123.123.123 port 80: Connexion refused`

Note that a difference has been detected when there is no visible difference between the subject name and target host name.

1. I have the certificate from the Gitlab server stored into a local `.pem` file (obtained via "`openssl s_client -connect`").
2. Exporting or adding "`IT_SSL_CAINFO=/path/to/cert/certs.pem`" before cloning does not change the behaviour.
3. The "`export GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=True`" tweak works (and is mentionned here and on other blogs/forums), but is also creating a vulnerability in the system (and kind of moots the point of using HTTPS :-p), so I don't want to rely on it.
4. If I deactivate SSL verification, then clone, then reactivate SSl verification, and try to pull or push, I get the same behavior.
5. Results for "`openssl s_client -connect 123.123.123.123:443`" (sorry about the formatting, I can't seem to get it right)(EDIT: I used this command to get the certificate locally, by copying from the line "BEGIN CERTIFICATE" to the line "END CERTIFICATE" to my local .pem file):

   ### CONNECTED(00000003)
   depth=0 CN = 123.123.123.123
   verify return:1

   ### Certificate chain
   0 s:/CN=123.123.123.123
   i:/CN=123.123.123.123

   ### Server certificate
   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
   [...]
   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
   subject=/CN=123.123.123.123
   issuer=/CN=123.123.123.123

   ### No client certificate CA names sent
   Peer signing digest: SHA256
   Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits

   ### SSL handshake has read 1404 bytes and written 433 bytes

   New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
   Server public key is 2048 bit
   Secure Renegotiation IS supported
   Compression: NONE
   Expansion: NONE
   No ALPN negotiated
   SSL-Session:
   Protocol  : TLSv1.2
   Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
   Session-ID: [...]
   Session-ID-ctx:
   Master-Key: [...]
   Key-Arg   : None
   PSK identity: None
   PSK identity hint: None
   SRP username: None
   TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
   TLS session ticket:
   [...]

   Start Time: [...]
   Timeout   : 300 (sec)
   Verify return code: 0 (ok)
6. Contents of my gitlab.rb file on the server file:

   #==============================================
   external_url "https://123.123.123.123"

   gitlab_rails['object_store']['enabled'] = false
   gitlab_rails['object_store']['connection'] = {}
   gitlab_rails['object_store']['storage_options'] = {}
   gitlab_rails['object_store']['proxy_download'] = false
   gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['artifacts']['bucket'] = nil
   gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['external_diffs']['bucket'] = nil
   gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['lfs']['bucket'] = nil
   gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['uploads']['bucket'] = nil
   gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['packages']['bucket'] = nil
   gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['dependency_proxy']['bucket'] = nil
   gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['terraform_state']['bucket'] = nil

   letsencrypt['enable'] = false
   #==============================================
7. Contents of my local .git/config file:

   #==============================================
   [core]
   repositoryformatversion = 0
   filemode = true
   bare = false
   logallrefupdates = true
   [remote "origin"]
   url = https://123.123.123.123/MyName/MyProject.git
   fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
   [branch "master"]
   remote = origin
   merge = refs/heads/master
   [http]
   sslVerify = true
   sslCAPath = /path/to/cert/certs.pem
   #==============================================

Comment: Is it a requirement that you access the server via HTTPS? For a server with self-signed certificate SSH access may be easier as SSH is always "trust on first use" (just like a self-signed certificate).

Comment: Does the certificate have an appropriate IP address entry in subjectAltNames?  CN is no longer used tor certificates, so if you lack a subjectAltName, then the certificate won't validate.  Alternatively, can you use DNS to get an appropriate Let's Encrypt certificate for this?

Comment: @Robert: Technically we could do both. My understanding is that we could do both (either use HTTPS or use a self-signed certificate inHTTP) but your comment makes sense in that doing both at the same time is redundant. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @bk2204: Using LetsEncrypt does indeed seems like the best way to do it. After reflecting on Robert's previous comment and reading more about Gitlab documentation, I think it seems the best way to do. Thank you both for your comments, I'll have a go with LetsEncrypt and I'll edit my post if this solves my problem.